# Statistical Decisions

Tags: statistics

Suppose $X \in \mathbb{R}^p$ and $Y \in \mathbb{R}$. Also suppose the joint distribution of $X$ and $Y$ is $\text{Pr}(X,Y)$. We want to find a function $f(X)$ for predicting $Y$. Let us choose squared error loss for our error function. In a sense, we want $f(X) \approx Y$. So the error function we are using is: $$L(Y,f(X)) = (Y-f(X))^{2}$$

Then the expected squared error loss is $$E[(Y-f(X))^{2}] = \int (y-f(x))^{2} P(dx,dy)$$

> **Question**. Why is this equal to: $$E_{X} E_{Y|X} ([(Y-f(X)]^{2}|X)$$

I know it boils down to $P(X,Y) = P(Y|X)P(X)$. But what does the above expecation mean intuitively? Do we first pick a value of $X$ and then compute $E[(Y-f(X))^2]$? We does this for all values of $X$ and then take the average?

Answer (score 0):

**Reason 1:**

We often care about the best decision when given $X$ but not $Y$. The scenario is usually that we are *given* a particular value of $x$ (not a likelihood) and must work out how best to act, deterministically, on this data. This "act" may be, or be determined by, an estimation.

**For each $x$ value, do the best thing possible**

In this case find the closest $f$ to $y$ according to the square error.

The best choice for each $x$ does not depend on the probability of $x$ unless there are some extra constraints. i.e. optimising for one $x$ conflicts with optimising for another $x$. This scenario is common in statistical inference, but less so in real world applications.

In the absence of these constraints on $f$, we can just optimise $f$ according to $\mathbb{E}_{Y|X} \mathcal{L}(Y,f(X))$ for each value of $x$ and $y$. The value of this is the loss for a single "decision"/"estimate".

We would then only take the expectation over $X$ if we wanted the the explicit expectation of the loss. This often introduces the need for a prior over $x$ or gathering of statistics, and it is nice to keep them out of the problem where possible.

So with free reign over $f$ we can break the equation down like:

$$\overbrace{\mathbb{E}_X\underbrace{\mathbb{E}_{Y|X}\mathcal{L}(Y,f(X))}_{\text{Loss for each x}}}^\text{Expected loss}$$

**Reason 2:**

It's nice to move as much as you can out of integrals:

$$\int_X\int_Y\int_Z f(x,y,z) kg(y,z) h(z) dx\, dy\, dz \rightarrow k\int_Z h(z) \int_Y g(y,z) \int_X f(x,y,z) dx\, dy\, dz$$

which is just making the [affordance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affordance) of the equation clearer.